# WebMatrix static code analysis for Umbraco dot net app

Tags: c#, umbraco, code-analysis, webmatrix, static-analysis

I am conducting an audit for an app being programmed by another developer. It is a dot net app, mostly c#, but obviously contains html, css, js, and some angular. This product was written using the CMS Umbraco, which means I can't open it in Visual Studio and must use WebMatrix. I have to run a static code analysis, code violation checker, and quality metrics report on the product. What tools should I use to run this reports and how to I run them inside WebMatrix? Visual Studio already has code analysis built in, but I can't find anything built into WebMatrix for this.

Comment: Try PVS-Studiuo tool. Example of check Umbraco by this analyzer - http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0357/

Comment: Why cant you use VS? Im using VS for all my Umbraco sites. You can also create a new VS project, install Umbraco from nuget, and then copy files over, and then point the DB to the old DB.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio solutions typically consist of a .sln file which may reference multiple project files (.csproj, .xproj...) but Visual Studio also supports opening Web projects from directories **File** > **Open** > **Web Site...** When exiting or Saving all VS will prompt you to create a new solution file for the Website making to quicker to open from VS next time.